# App won't sign into google account from phone, but ok from emulator

Tags: java, android, google-account

I am working on an app that is using google account sign it feature, when running on emulator, it logs in normally to google service account, but once I install in phone it doesn't work.

```
if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
    GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
    if (result.isSuccess()) {
        Log.d(TAG,"Success");
        Googleaccount = result.getSignInAccount();
    } else{
        Log.e(TAG,"Fail");
    }
    updateUI();
}
```

So, I get Success from code above when using emulator, but getting Fail when using phone.

```
[GoogleAccountDataServiceImpl] getToken() -> NETWORK_ERROR. Account: <ELLIDED:XXXXXXXXXX>, App: com.XXXXX.XXXXXX, Service: oauth2:email openid profile
```

Comment: And the status message you are getting back is...

Comment: Try logging some more useful information about `result` or `resultCode` rather than `"FAIL"`

Comment: Sorry, update question.

Comment: resultcode is 0 BTW

Comment: Sorry all, I am being stupid :(    as it is saying Network error, my WIFI was off

Answer (score 1):

My phone's WIFI was off.
Turned it on and worked fine